# how to use setMethodCallHandler

Tags: ios, flutter

something wrong with my code, I want send message to Flutter.

```
static const channel = MethodChannel('foo');

channel.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) async {
  switch (call.method) {
    case 'bar':
      return 'Hello, ${call.arguments}';
    default:
      throw MissingPluginException();
  }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Do you need the implementation for iOS or Flutter side? Secondly did you check this link https://flutter.io/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels ?

Comment: See the linked answer. If you still have problems, update the question with more of the code (including the imports).

Comment: static const _channel = const MethodChannel('samples.flutter.io/battery');
_channel.setMethodCallHandler(myUtilsHandler);
there is an error prompt with _channel;
"Invalid constructor name.dart(invalid_constructor_name)"

Comment: When I move "_channel.setMethodCallHandler(myUtilsHandler);" in  initState method, It work.